# Why casting failed when used swf loader

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, adobe

Any class common between flash swf file, loaded in swfloader turns our to throw error

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 
media::PlayerContentView@12babac1 to media.PlayerContentView.
```

My main swf has same class, since its been used by appplication all over, but when swfloader creates object of same name class, it adds **12babac1**  to class name. and doesn't work for simple access of array values

```
public function get Current():media.PlayerContentView
{
    return contentItems[VZPlay.CurrentIndex] as PlayerContentView;
}
```

where as this same code works very fine if Its just the child swf played on it own.

Comment: Found it myself, I just saw loadForCompatibility property for swfloader.

http://www.scribd.com/doc/12990361/Developing-and-loading-subapplications

URL may not work, the owner made it private, but setting this property to false make it work all fine.

e.g.

    <mx:SWFLoader id="swfMain" width="480" height="270" scaleContent="true" 
    loadForCompatibility="false" />

Comment: +1 I didn't know about loadForCompatibility. Answer your own question and then mark it as accepted so that it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Comment: I got to know about loadForCapatibility from the URL above. I can't set it answered since stack is really annoying UI sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself, I just saw loadForCompatibility property for swfloader. scribd.com/doc/12990361/Developing-and-loading-subapplications URL may not work, the owner made it private, but setting this property to false make it work all fine. e.g.